# A bash script that takes an argument that uses it in a docker bash command?

Tags: bash, docker, shell

So say I have a bash script that takes two arguments.

```
./myBash.sh 123 "123123"
```

Cool we can do something like

```
index=$1 
location=$2
```

How do I use those arguments in a docker command within `myBash.sh`

like:

```
docker exec myDockerContainer_1 bash -c 'myMigrationScript --pw=$location  --pwOld=1234 --indexToStartAt=$index'
```

But this doesn't seem to work?
The variables do not get carried over inside the docker container?

Comment: its probably because you are using single quote `'`, you need to use double quotes `"`

Answer (score 0):

If you set this in your Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c"]
CMD ["/path/to/myBash.sh"]
```

Then you only need

```
docker run --rm image arg1 arg2
```